# Merge postgres, postgres-8.4, postgres-8.3 into postgresql

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, merge

Just noticed that there's a bunch of questions that are tagged [postgres](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postgres), or [postgres-8.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postgres-8.4), [postgres-8.3](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postgres-8.3); all need to by synonyms of [postgresql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great suggestion; all merged into [postgresql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)